# Deterministic Random access machine and polynomial time

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time

How do we prove $M$ that is a deterministic random access machine that decides a problem $A$ for an input $i$, and $u_M(i)$ is the set of addresses of those registers that occur at least once with $s$ steps and a configuration of $C_0,\dots,C_s$ where each configuration is of the form $C_i=(k_i,R_i)$, were $k_i$ is the program counter and a mapping $R_i$ runs in polynomial time if it runs in logarithmic space.

Comment: Standard textbook exercise. What have you done so far?

Comment: What I have done so far is that the maximal configuration for a problem that is is decidable in $log(x)$ space is $2^{o(used(x))}$ since each space can either be used or unused and this is the total number of configuration possible. Just want to  know if I am on the right track and besides @G.Bach what is the point of posting a question you already know

Comment: The point is that you showed no effort besides posting the question, and this website is not here to solve exercises for people. I couldn't know whether you had done anything, there are quite a lot of people who come here and expect solutions to problems they have not even tried to solve. That is one of the reasons why this network expects people to also post what they tried when they post a question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the program runs in logarithmic space then there are only polynomially many possible configurations.